# What's the difference between command upload and browser upload in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I know there are various ways to upload my code into github.

One is using command line.

Another is using github web.

Is there any difference when I use one of this way?

Comment: What kind of differences? Why are you asking? You have a lot more control when using git from the command line or from a graphical client as opposed to using github's file upload.

Comment: With browser file upload you won't be able to handle merges or anything, and won't be able to leverage the full power of git as a collaborative tool.

Comment: A mouse? Lol. No difference in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform the same actions:

- add a new file(s) or edit a file(s)
- use the same commit message
- on the same branch

using command-line or using the **upload** feature of github.com, then the result will be the same.

But you'd better learn using the **command-line** `git` interface which is so much more powerful!